# ¿Por qué cuando algo nos sorprende decimos que "nos quedamos a cuadros"?

Tags: etimología, modismos, expresiones, coloquialismos, españa

Hoy en una charla alguien ha usado esta expresión y me ha parecido una buena pregunta para el *stack*. Le he echado un vistazo al DRAE para la entrada de "[cuadro](https://dle.rae.es/?id=BQQYOon)" y me he encontrado, que sea relevante, con las acepción

> 7. m. En un espectáculo teatral, grupo de intérpretes que **en algunos momentos permanecen estáticos** ante el público.

y entre las locuciones

> cuadro vivo
>
> 1. m. Representación de una obra de arte o de una escena por personas que permanecen inmóviles y en silencio.

(curioso que se llame "cuadro **vivo**" precisamente cuando los actores permanecen "inmóviles y en silencio.")

> estar, o quedarse, en cuadro (que no "a cuadros")

Que viene a significar "Quedar reducido a un corto número de miembros." ("Haber perdido su familia o sus bienes de fortuna, quedándose aislado" / "Estar, o quedarse, sin tropa, conservando sus jefes, oficiales, sargentos y cabos")

y curiosamente "quedarse **a cuadros**" no viene. Quizá se usa solo en España.

Viendo esas acepciones y locuciones, podría entenderse que

> Me he **quedado a cuadros**. Estoy muy sorprendido y extrañado

puede venir de esas representaciones donde los actores "permanecen estáticos y en silencio" (me he quedado tan sorprendido que estoy inmóvil y en silencio, como una estatua) pero no cuadra del todo que la locución sea "a cuadros" en lugar de "en cuadro" (y "quedarse a cuadro" tiene su propio significado, que es diferente).

Dado que un cuadro es también

> 3. m. Composición pictórica desarrollada sobre lienzo, madera, papel, etc., generalmente enmarcada.

puede ser que tenga algo que ver también con el "quedarse estático", pero de nuevo, no decimos "quedarse como un cuadro" si no "a cuadros".

¿Cuál es entonces el origen de la expresión "quedarse a cuadros" para indicar sorpresa?

Comment: ¿Necesitará esta pregunta una etiqueta de región? Nunca lo he oído aquí en Colombia.

Comment: @DGaleano No la puse porque no estoy preguntando por su uso o si se entiende en una región concreta. Como ya digo en la pregunta, entiendo que el uso de este coloquialismo es restringido, ya que la locución no está siquiera documentada en el DRAE. Pero tienes razán, conviene ponerla y así es más fácil buscar preguntas sobre coloquialismos o expresiones que se usen solo en España.

Comment: Ignoro si tenga alguna relación pero en México se usa cualquier varaición de la expresión **quedarse con el ojo cuadrado** que significa quedar en un completo estado de sorpresa.

Answer (score 2):

Es una metáfora para las personajes inmóviles y silencios de un cuadro:

> Entre las metáforas de corte estructural cabe destacar casos como p. ej. el concepto *"quedarse asombrado"*, expresado mediante el dominio de la *"inmovilidad"*, con distintas variantes: *quedarse de piedra; **quedarse a cuadros**; quedarse muerto; quedarse blanco; quedarse pasmado; quedarse pegado; quedarse boquiabierto;* etc.
>
> - [*Actas del XXIII Congreso Internacional de Linguística y Filología Románica:*
>
>     Salamanca, 24-30 septiembre 2001, Volume 2, Part 1](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=NQ-yDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA4&dq=quedarse+"a+cuadros")

Nota que, aunque puede parecer más lógico decir 'como un cuadro', las locuciones adverbiales se forman de muchas maneras:

> No obstante, algunos complementos mantienen con el verbo
>   una relación más estrecha, por lo que ya no pueden considerarse
>   marginales. El verbo selecciona diversas locuciones que
>   completan su significación, de manera que se establece una
>   especie de selección léxica entre ambos. En esta circunstancia se
>   encuentran las locuciones que complementan a verbos de
>   estado, a verbos de lengua, a verbos de percepción, etc. Se ha de
>   resaltar que las locuciones adverbiales que manifiestan esta
>   correspondencia son precisamente las de modo o manera y no
>   las temporales o locativas.
>
> ...
>
> Buena parte de las locuciones registradas aparecen con verbos de estado, como "estar", "dejar" o "quedarse", pese a que los significados de las locuciones son diversos: ***a cuadros***, de piedra, con la boca abierta, con un palmo de narices, de mal humor, de perfil, de plantón, en blanco, en el aire...
>
> - [*La Fraseología Del Español Coloquial*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=LpsdAQAAIAAJ), Leonor Ruíz (1998)
>     <sub>(2. Sintaxis | 2. 1. Locuciones adverbiales | 2. 1. 1. Como modificadores del verbo)</sub>